# Annoying problem with hotkeys

Tags: keyboard, interface

How to prevent Mathematica from using its internal hotkey grammar while pressing the standard combinations like ctrl+c, ctrl+v etc.? In my case, after some period of using of Mathematica, instead of copying the text by pressing ctrl+c it opens Wolfram Demonstrations Project (WDP)...

Edit

Even more, it launches the notebook with WDP even when clicking File->Save button, so I can't save my working project! What is the reason for this bug (working with Mathematica 10)?

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that the suggestions that pop up after output cells in more recent versions are easy to accidentally activate. There is also an autocomplete-type menu that pops up when certain characters are typed. This 2nd menu captures key input that would normally go into the editor, which is annoying if you're used to the `Escape`-Character_Name-`Escape` method of input from older versions. Exiting the menu itself uses up an escape, so if you happen to activate it, the number of escapes you need is altered by one (!!). I've found myself accidentally activating all sorts of things because the keystrokes that worked in the old versions which no longer work that way.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/121